# How to access two different onclicklisteners with one button based on a boolean

Tags: android, buttonclick

Based on the user selection I would like to open one activity or another when the button is pressed. I've also tried to set only one Listener and inside of it depending on the boolean to intent one activity or another but that got me the "Variable is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared at final " error. Thank you!

```
 but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);

    RadioButton selectionA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectionA);
    boolean VocabularySelected = selectionA.isChecked();

    RadioButton selectionB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectionB);
    boolean MathSelected = selectionB.isChecked();

    if (VocabularySelected) {
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent Vocabulary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VocabularyActivity.class);
                startActivity(Vocabulary);
            }
        });
    }
    if (MathSelected) {
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent Math = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MathActivity.class);
                startActivity(Math);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view can only have one `OnClickListener` assigned to it, so you will need to check to see which path to take from within the listener.

To avoid errors regarding access of non-final variables, you can perform the check in another fashion. Maybe something like this:

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        RadioButton selectionA = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectionA);
        RadioButton selectionB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectionB);

        if (selectionA.isChecked()) {
            Intent Vocabulary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VocabularyActivity.class);
            startActivity(Vocabulary);
        else if (selectionB.isChecked()) {
            Intent Math = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MathActivity.class);
            startActivity(Math);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the same click listener and inside it you do your logic depending your boolean?

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (MathSelected) {
                Intent Math = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MathActivity.class);
                startActivity(Math);
            } else if(VocabularySelected) {
                Intent Vocabulary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VocabularyActivity.class);
                startActivity(Vocabulary);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you can do it, here is one of my favorites, by referencing the view itself inside the listener:

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectionA)).isChecked()) {
                Intent Vocabulary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VocabularyActivity.class);
                startActivity(Vocabulary);
            } else if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSelectionB)).isChecked()) {
                Intent Math = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MathActivity.class);
                startActivity(Math);
            }
        }
    });
```

It is not the most readable one, but the shortest.

You could also declare your boolean variables as members of the class, and use them both in one listener like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
...
    private boolean mVocabularyChecked, mMathChecked;
...
    private void yourMethod() {
        but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVocabularyChecked) {
                    Intent Vocabulary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VocabularyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(Vocabulary);
                } else if (mMathChecked) {
                    Intent Math = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MathActivity.class);
                    startActivity(Math);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```